# How to get wall post made by myself on friends' wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to fetch wall posts made by myself on friends'wall. I've read_stream, offline_access permission.

Now as per the facebook documentation, if I want to fetch wall posts made by other users on my wall, I can use following FQL Query :

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = me()
```

If I want to get wall post made by my self, I came up with the following FQL Query :

```
select post_id,source_id,actor_id,target_id from stream where actor_id=me() and filter_key='Others'
```

Which sometimes works and sometimes don't work. I tried below query as well which returns nothing.

```
select post_id,source_id,actor_id,target_id from stream where actor_id=me() and source_id in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Now following works but I've to check for individual friend.

```
select post_id,source_id,actor_id,target_id from stream where actor_id=me() and source_id = <uid>
```

Is there any way to do it in single go?

Edit:

Following query return wall post made on friend's wall but it doesn't return all the wall post. i.e If user post on friends' wall consecutively, it will display the last one instead of both the posts.

```
select description, post_id,actor_id,source_id,target_id,created_time  from stream where source_id=me()  and type = 56
```

Comment: your second query says Others with a capital O which is invalid. Did you just mistype it?

Comment: I just mistyped it. As I said, it works intermittently and not provide the complete data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a person has to be in some role (developer,tester,admin) for the given app. If that is not the case he'll not be able to access the facebook bug tracking system. Unfortunately the person who created the app forgot to add me as developer to the app.